# Calculate the integral $n^2 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} e^{-x^2}\sin(x) \mathrm{d}x$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I am tring to calculate the limit of the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-x^2}\sin{x}\ \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
Since it's difficult to apply integration by parts, I want to substitute $\sin{x}$ with its Taylor expansion: $\sin{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. And note the function series is convergent, but after calculation I found they're all vanish before multiply $n^2$. What's wrong with my attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By L'Hopital's Rule $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac 1 {t^{2}}\int_0^{t} e^{-x^{2}} \sin x dx=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac 1 {2t} e^{-t^{2}} \sin t=\frac 1 2$ since $\frac {\sin t} t \to 1$ and $e^{-t^{2}} \to 1$ . Put $t=\frac  1n$.

Comment: My bad, I almost forget the easy L'Hopital's rule in this case.

Answer (score 3):

As $x\to0,$
$$e^{-x^2}\sin x\sim x$$ hence as $n\to\infty,$
$$n^2\int_0^{1/n}e^{-x^2}\sin x\ \mathrm dx\sim n^2\int_0^{1/n}x\ \mathrm dx=\frac12.$$

Comment: ! How do you prove $e^{-x^2}$sin x is of order x? Please explain.

Comment: "Of order" is not precise. I use $\sim.$ $e^{-x^2}\to1$ and $\sin x\sim x.$ The usual [definition of $\sim$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) (as $x\to$ some $a\in[-\infty,+\infty]$) is: $f\sim g$ iff $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to1.$

Answer (score 3):

Let me add one more solution using the fundamental theorem of calculus:
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-x^2}\sin{x}\ \mathrm{d}x\\
=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{h}\int_{0}^{\sqrt h}e^{-x^2}\sin{x}\ \mathrm{d}x\\
(x^2\rightarrow t)=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{h}\int_{0}^{h}e^{-t} \frac{\sin{\sqrt t}}{2\sqrt t}\mathrm{d}t\\
=&\lim_{t\to0}e^{-t} \frac{\sin{\sqrt t}}{2\sqrt t}\\
=&\lim_{s\to0}e^{-s^2} \frac{\sin{s}}{2s}\\
=&\frac12
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will like this method. By MVT for integrals, there is $c_n\in(0,\frac1n)$ such that
$$n^2\int_0^{1/n}e^{-x^2}\sin x\ \mathrm dx=n^2e^{-c_n^2}\int_0^{1/n}\sin x\ \mathrm dx=n^2e^{-c_n^2}(1-\cos(\frac1n))=\frac12e^{-c_n^2}n^2\sin^2(\frac1{2n})\to\frac12$$
as $n\to\infty$.